# golang gotk3 при переключении языка вылетает

Tags: golang, gui, gtk3

Отловил странный баг, даже простейшее приложение "Hello, gotk3!" вылетает при изменении раскладки клавиатуры. Причём не важно, переключение было произведено горячими клавишами или мышкой по иконке. 
Windows 7 x64, go version go1.11.4 windows/amd64

```
>go run sample.go
exit status 3221226356
```

Ошибку отловили на почти законченном приложении. Потом проверили на "привет мир" - те-же проблемы. 
Дополнительные проверки показали что программа крашится при переключении на любой не Английский язык. Т.е. пери переключении с EN на RU или с RU на UK или с EN на UK - крашится. Но! При переключении на EN нормально отрабатывает. 
Так-же например при переключении с RU на UK программа может дополнительно поменять язык на EN.

Попробовал подебажить

```
>dlv debug sample.go
Type 'help' for list of commands.
(dlv) continue
Stopped at: 0x772ef3b0
=>no source available
(dlv) continue
Process 2700 has exited with status 3221226356
(dlv)
```

Пример Sample Use -> "Hello, gotk3!", с [гит-хаба](https://github.com/gotk3/gotk3)

Comment: Подкиньте выхлоп с паникой, будьте так любезны. Может это GTK тухнет, а может gotk. Полагаю, что всё из-за кодировки в Windows.

Comment: @IvanBlack Добавил "выхлоп", после переключения раскладки Stopped at: 0x772ef3b0
=>no source available.

Comment: Нужно обновить GTK3 до 3.24.3. Но там появятся [новые проблемы](https://github.com/gotk3/gotk3/issues/296) уже с gotk.

Comment: @IvanBlack Спасибо за ваше участие. Об этом уже было написано в тикете https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/issues/1596#note_414514 открытом после того как выявили, что это таки проблемы в GTK, а не с gotk https://github.com/gotk3/gotk3/issues/324. В общем по ситуации "на сейчас" после обновления до mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3 3.24.3-1  переключение  заработало. Ещё раз спасибо за ваше участие.